# Programmatically updating a node

Tags: 8, nodes

I can create a node using the following code:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create($array);
```

But if I have the node ID, how can I *edit* a node?

Comment: what you want to edit? which field?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try this code

```
<?php
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::load($nid);
//set value for field
$node->body->value = 'body';
$node->body->format = 'full_html';
//field tag
$node->field_tags = [1];
//field image
$field_image = array(
    'target_id' => $fileID,
    'alt' => "My 'alt'",
    'title' => "My 'title'",
);
$node->field_image = $field_image;

//save to update node
$node->save();
```

Comment: This answer is not the good way, Ivan answer is the good answer

Comment: I don't think any of these answer the original question very well. Is it possible to take an array of values (like in Node::create) and update an existing node? Or, do you need to go through each array item and ->set() fields as the answers above seem to suggest?

Comment: @liquidcms a entity have method *toArray* return an array of property values, keyed by property name ($node->toArray()). You can use for each and set value for value for the field you want to update.

Answer (score 8):

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Entity's API to perform the updates.

```
$node = Node::load($id);

if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
  try {
    $node->set('title', 'My Title');
    $node->set('field_textfield', 'My textfield value');
    $node->save();
  }
  catch (\Exception $e) {
    watchdog_exception('myerrorid', $e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old method works too for me:

```
$node=node_load($nid);
print_r($node->body->format);
$node->body->format='full_html';
print_r($node->body->format);
$node->save();
```

Comment: node_load is deprecated in Drupal 8.x, will be removed before Drupal 9.0. Use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(). Ref https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/8.3.x